# grails domain-class validator troubles testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have a validator inside a domain class and I have a problem testing the controller for Lagerort.

```
com.example.xyz.LagerortControllerSpec > Test the update action performs an update on a valid domain instance FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [com.example.xyz.Lagertyp] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
```

If I omit the validator, everything tests fine, but that's not what I want.

The domain class:

```
 class Lagerort {

     String lagerort
     Lagertyp lagertyp
     String beschreibung

     static auditable = true

     static constraints = {
         lagerort(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
         lagertyp(nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
             // Only ONE Lagerort may be "Schrott"
             if (Lagertyp.count() > 0) {
                 def _LAGERTYPSTRING="Schrott"
                 Lagertyp lagertypschrott = Lagertyp.findByLagertyp(_LAGERTYPSTRING)
                 if (obj.lagertyp == lagertypschrott && Lagerort.countByLagertyp(lagertypschrott)>0) return ['lagerortschrottunique',_LAGERTYPSTRING]
             }
         })
         beschreibung(nullable: false, blank: false)

     }

     String toString(){lagerort}
 }
```

The testCompile part of the dependencies in build.gradle looks like this:

```
testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
```

I've already tried creating a few objects of type Lagertyp in the setup part of the controller tests so that `Lagertyp.count() > 0` would be true for the validator, but that didn't help either.

The populateValidParams of the LagerortControllerSpec / test looks like this:

```
def populateValidParams(params) {
    assert params != null
    params["lagerort"] = 'Fa.Conrad'
    params["lagertyp"] = ["lagertyp": 'Fa.Conrad', "beschreibung": 'Motor befindet sich bei Fa.Conrad']
    params["beschreibung"] = 'in Reparatur bei Fa. Conrad'
}
```

The LagerortController: https://pastebin.com/PpZ5zqMm

The test for LagerortController: https://pastebin.com/pxZ6UeVK

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to also mock Lagertyp, like so:

```
@Mock([Lagerort,Lagertyp])
```

It seems that I have to include all domain classes which are part of the tests inside the `@Mock` list, even those that are referenced indirectly.